# Play! Framework, multiple processors and multiple cores

Tags: playframework, multiprocessing

Just wondering how to read following Play guideline:

`Default to 1 thread in DEV mode or (nb processors + 1) threads in PROD mode.`

So if I have 2 CPUs with 4 cores each, is the recommended number 3 (2 processors + 1), or is it 9 (2 processors * 4 cores + 1).

As far as I know, each core executes instructions independently, so that seems to imply the second option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested that on 4 cores 8 threads i7 CPU with:

```
System.out.println("Cores: " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
System.out.println("Threads: " + Invoker.executor.getCorePoolSize());
```

In application init job and results are:

DEV mode:
Cores: 8
Threads: 1

PROD mode:
Cores: 8
Threads: 9

So it looks that it simply uses what Java finds - CPU threads